# How to return a message if a Password Recovery query is not match Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, authentication, linq-to-sql

I am working with an password recovery function on my login system.

The requirements of the password recovery form was to authenticate the three values: `username, security question and security answer`. If the query returns a `null` it will return a `messagebox`. My problem is when one of the three values are not true it returns an error `"Sequence contains no elements"`.

I use an `try-catch` statement and it sorted this problem but I don't want to use that method because it is slow and not recommended by my professor.

Do you have any alternative for try-catch statement or any one have an alternative solution for password recovery function wherein the three values must be validated first before returning the password.

PS: I didn't have any encryption method on my password as I want to make this work first.

```
 var t = new DataClasses1DataContext();
 tbl_Register r = null;


 r = t.tbl_Registers.Single(p => p.u_username == textBox1.Text && p.u_secquestion == comboBox1.Text && p.u_secanswer == textBox2.Text);


 if (r == null) {
  MessageBox.Show("account is not found in the database");

 } else {
  MessageBox.Show("your password is:\t" + r.u_password);
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried .FirstOrDefault() instead of Single() ?

Comment: All (technically correct) answers aside - if you're on the .NET stack, why not use the [Authentication Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx) that comes with it. It has everything you're about to build from scratch (including security question, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `.Single` to `.FirstOrDefault`. i don't know what values you're storing in database. but let's say if you're inserting similar records you'll get more than one records which match. in that case, `.single` will throw an exception.

`.Single` should be used when you expect one and only one record returned.

`.FirstOrDefault` is used when the query might return more than 0, 1 or more than one records, but you're interested in only on of those.

Comment: `Single` is not an issue here but not taking care of `default null` is an issue

Comment: @MrinalKamboj actually yes. `Single` might be the issue. `Single` will also give exception if there're more than one records found. and yes, it'll give exception in case of null too. i suggested `FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault` since idk if he's using similar records. it's a school project so i guess the OP would insert multiple similar records which in turn would cause problems with `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying me about the Single and FirstOrDefault Thing.

Comment: @GerardSantos no problem. have fun coding.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code as following, since it is quite possible there's no element returned, and result is `null`. Currently you are forcing it to read a `Single element` which doesn't exist, thus an exception. remaining code will work fine post it

```
r = t.tbl_Registers.SingleOrDefault(p => p.u_username == textBox1.Text 
                                    && p.u_secquestion == comboBox1.Text 
                                    && p.u_secanswer == textBox2.Text);
```